# Unable to start project after create-react-app: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pcname\Documents\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I created a small react project using npx create-react-app to work on some react tutorials but I am unable to start the react app. This i the error that I get when trying to run the project:

```
> test-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\pcname\Documents\React R&D\Pluralsight\test-app
> react-scripts start

'D\Pluralsight\test-app\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pcname\Documents\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pcnmame\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-08T22_43_14_881Z-debug.log
```

I've uninstalled node, reinstalled it. Install react-scripts globally and not globally. I've replaced the start script in the package.json to be:

```
"start": "node node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js"
```

and that works. I've also run react-scripts start inside the app folder and again, that works!! But I can't get it to work when I do npm start inside the app folder

Bonus: Any tutorials setting up React in Visual Studio (not vs code) without using ASP NET Core would be appreciated. I'm currently unable to set up the debugger with VS.

Answer (score 2):

This error can happen after you use `create-react-app` in case you have some invalid character in your path.

Remove `&` from your path.

Change from this:

```
C:\Users\pcname\Documents\React R&D\Pluralsight\test-app
```

To this:

```
C:\Users\pcname\Documents\React RD\Pluralsight\test-app
```

It should work now!

Answer (score 0):

re-running `npm i` solved my problem.
I had the same problem, turns out "reinstalling" npm packages gets rid of the annoying

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pcname\Documents\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
> .
> .
> .
> {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: []
> }

error message.